# How to hide Progress Bar in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am creating an Android project in which I have created a Webview. When the page loads, the progress bar runs. When the page is 100% loaded then the progress bar becomes hidden

But i don't know how to hide it

**ProgressBar Code**:

```
@Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view,int newProgress)
            {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                superProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);

            }
```

**All Code**:

```
package com.djaman.musicwala;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    ProgressBar superProgressBar;
    ImageView superImageView;
    WebView superWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        superWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        superProgressBar =  (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.myProcessBar);
        superImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);

        superProgressBar.setMax(100);

        superWebView.loadUrl("http://musicwala.cf");
        superWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        superWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        superWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view,int newProgress)
            {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                superProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);

            }
            @Override
            public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view,String title)
            {
                super.onReceivedTitle(view, title);


            }
            @Override
            public void onReceivedIcon(WebView view,Bitmap icon)
            {
                super.onReceivedIcon(view, icon);
                superImageView.setImageBitmap(icon);
            }
        });

    }



    private WebView findViewById()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        if(superWebView.canGoBack())
        {
            superWebView.goBack();
        }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this in your "onProgressChanged()".

```
if (newProgress == 100) {
    superProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else {
    superProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    superProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
}
```

Comment: Sorry But I'm Getting An error :- unknown method 'setVisible' Of 'android.widget.progressBar'

Comment: It’s ‘setVisibility’

Comment: Yes It's Working Thank You